# Need to collapse inner arrays of and array of objects (with nested arrays)

Tags: javascript, arrays, nested, nested-object

I am calling the Tempo API to get timelogs for multiple users. My function loops through rows in a table and calls the API for each, returning an array of objects with nested arrays of 'results' - which is what I need to access.

The data returned is in this structure:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CGNN.png)

I want to just have an array of [results] so I can access the relevant keys I need and set each in a row of a table.

I have checked similar posts and tried suggestions but can't find one that works. Any help greatly appreciated!

Nick

I've tried this suggested approach:

var flattened = [].concat.apply({}, data);

However I still get back the [results] nested inside array [0].results [1].results etc

Also reviewed this post but can't find a solution that works for me on this:

[text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/how-can-i-access-and-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Comment: You can use [`.flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) (see examples from the link above your question on how to use it)

Comment: Thanks so much @NickParsons - const res = arr.flatMap(({ results }) => results) works perfectly.